# Using bcrypt in chrome extension

Tags: password-management, chrome, bcrypt

I am developing a chrome extension for this non profit. Im also working on the server side component as well. Im not a full time developer so most of my knowledge has simply come from years of collecting random information. One thing this program needs to do is login to the server and retrieve a code unique to the user. Luckily from how its working out in my mind we dont need to store the password, only retrieve and store their unique ID. However we will need to login to get that ID.

So my question, is if I use bcrypt in javascript to hash the password within the extension and then send the email + hash over to the server (via https of course), is there any security risk here? Im not thinking of one off of the top of my head but I just figured I would consult a few people who live in this world on a regular basis. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to store the password? Why are you hashing a password, then?

Comment: We are storing the password on the server itself, not on the client extension. I guess I could just send the password itself raw but through SSL but Id personally feel more comfortable for some reason if I didnt.

Comment: Whatever you send to the server *is* the password.

Comment: @stevo81989 If you do not trust the SSL connection then you already have lost. It does not matter then if you send the pasword or its hash.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a security risk?  No.

Is there a security advantage?  No.

Using HTTPS means that the password is protected in transit, and that it is being sent to the server you intend to.  Hashing the password client-side and sending the hash gains nothing: an attacker in a position to look inside the SSL tunnel and steal a plain-text password (eg. malware installed on the client) can instead steal the hash and pass it when impersonating the user.

As a side note, there are problems with hashing or encryption in Javascript.  Using a browser extension rather than in-page Javascript avoids many of them, but there's still a speed issue: Javascript is slow compared to native code, so you can't afford anywhere near as many rounds of bcrypt hashing.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess that I personally felt more comfortable with a hash being sent as opposed to a raw password. In regards to speed, Im not super concerned about it. The login will be a one time operation to receive an ID and that ID is then stored locally. It wouldnt be something that needs to happen every login.

Answer (score 0):

Please read Thomas Pornin's [canonical answer to How to securely hash passwords](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31846/39623), particularly the section

> Since hashing is (deliberately) expensive, it could make sense, in a client-server situation, to harness the CPU of the connecting clients. After all, when 100 clients connect to a single server, the clients collectively have a lot more muscle than the server.
>
> To perform client-side hashing, the communication protocol must be enhanced to support sending the salt back to the client. This implies an extra round-trip, when compared to the simple client-sends-password-to-server protocol. This may or may not be easy to add to your specific case.
>
> Client-side hashing is difficult in a Web context because the client uses Javascript, which is quite anemic for CPU-intensive tasks.
>
> In the context of SRP, password hashing necessarily occurs on the client side.

The upshot is that you can feel free to perform hashing client side, **HOWEVER this in no way changes the requirements to hash the result server-side prior to storage in a database or other data store**.

No matter what the client sends you to validate who they are, you must hash it server-side with a large number of iterations of PBKDF2, BCrypt, or SCrypt, so that someone with a leaked copy of your password/authentication database must still do meaningful amounts of work to authenticate to your app.

You do need to store the ServerBcrypt(ClientBcrypt(password, lots),evenmorelots) iteration count/work factor and salts so as to have something to authenticate whatever the alleged user provides you.

Comment: Thanks, I was pretty confident what I was doing before would be good. I am using bcrypt on the server side to store the password in the database. I know that since its an SSL from the client to the server than then a raw password should be sufficiently secure but I figured hashing it first client side would be just a slight way to increase the security. Thanks!